# Coded UI : Handling IE Modal Dialogs

Tags: coded-ui-tests

How do you handle IE Modal Dialog Windows in CodedUI ?

A Code snippet would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not help with your specific tests.  I have a test where I'm entering random data via code and never know what to expect.  On some occasions, this randomization will trigger a dialog box for certain fields.

I have code that will check for a BrowerDialogAction but on occasions when a dialog doesnt exists, it will fail.  Here is the solution:

```
try
        {
            BrowserWindow browserWindow = new BrowserWindow();
            browserWindow.PerformDialogAction(BrowserDialogAction.Ok);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // If a popup does not exists and an error is thrown, continue...
            Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;
        }
```

I realize this isn't the best solution but it works for me.  Lambda and other searches for the dialog will fail if it does not exists.  This will click the "ok" button if one exists.  If not, it will throw an error and continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try check for modal window appearances by checking if your main window .HasFocus property is true.

Recording the test with clicking in the opened modal window should work fine, so simply record the test without writing explicit code to find it.